# css position with percent

Tags: css, position

I have a problem with position divs relative in an other div.

I want to make a div that is position in the horizontal middle of the screen and in this div I want to place 3 other div with the same height. But all of them should be responsive.

A picture says more than words :)

[image]

```
<div id="zwrapper">
 <div id="z1" class="row"></div>
 <div id="z2" class="row"></div>
 <div id="z3" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

The blu element is the HTML

```
html{
  background: steelblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0; left:0; bottom: 0; right:0;
}
```

The lime one ist that div `(#zwrapper)` where I want to add the three red divs.

```
#zwrapper{
  height: 81%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: lime;
}
```

The red divs make problems. All divs have a height of 30%. The first one should be aligned to top and the third to bottom. The middle div with the id `#z2` is the only one which get a margin of `5%`.

```
.row{
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  background: red;
  height: 30%;
 }
 #z2{
  margin: 5% 0;
 }
```

My idea was to put the 3 divs with a height of 30% into the wrapper and give the middle one a margin (top / bottom) of 5% so I get a height of 100%. 
But this does not work.

If I resize the window in width, the height of the red divs changes though I don't change the height.

I make a fiddle to demonstrate this. http://jsfiddle.net/ELPJM/

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want scroll after resizing the width of window ? you should your media queries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that percent values in `margin` are always relative to width, not height. You can achieve this by using absolute positioning instead, and setting a "top" value on each row. Like this:

```
.row {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    background: red;
    height: 30%;
}

#z1 {
    top: 0%;
}

#z2 {
    top: 35%;
}

#z3 {
    top: 70%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ELPJM/8/

Comment: not just what i was looking for, but it works and doesnt react with a change of width. THANKS!!

Comment: What if condition to use relative only ! why absolute, it causes totally different concept

Comment: @user1635700 this answer was from several years ago. nowadays i would suggest using flexbox. Google it, but it allows to cleanly specify exact behavior without using hacks like this.

Comment: Its will crash any how, better and best if background images. make best and centric test too

Answer (score 2):

It's your `margin: 5% 0;` that makes the height change. I'm not sure what margin-top and -bottom measures its percentage from but its not from the same as the parent element height.
Therefore you cant use it to count it towards 100% height.

try this instead:

```
<div id="zwrapper">
    <div id="z1" class="row"></div>
    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div id="z2" class="row"></div>
    <div class="spacing"></div>
    <div id="z3" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

with the styling:

```
.spacing{ height: 5%; }
```

Comment: works well, thank you! but the other with position: absolute is simpler in implementation

Comment: Of course! why didnt i think of that, its a much better solution. but hey, now you know where the height-difference came from :)

Comment: yes, the description of reason was very helpful for the future :)

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div id="zwrapper">
    <div class="holder">
        <div id="z1" class="row"></div>
        <div id="z2" class="row"></div>
        <div id="z3" class="row"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height: 100%;}
#zwrapper{min-height: 100%;}
#zwrapper:after{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1px;
}
#zwrapper.holder{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should solve it

```
.row{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: red;
    height: 30%;
}
#z2{
    margin: 5% auto;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect that downvote was because this just doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/ELPJM/9/

Comment: i didn't downvote,too. but auto as second value makes imho the div centered in the middle.. and still reacts to a change of width