# Liferay 6.2 layout rows of different sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row-height, liferay-6.2

I have created a Liferay 6.2 Layout having four rows in single column where portlets are placed. The layout rendered correctly but the issue is that I need the four rows to have different height such as 15%, 25%, 30%, 30% which makes 100%. Can we do this at the layout side itself, so that it can be generic wherever I use this Layout

Can anyone please tell me how to do that

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2

What I am trying to achieve is something like this as shown below

[image]

My liferay layout code is as given below

**template.tpl**

```
<div class="layout1template" id="main-content" role="main">
        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12" id="column-1">
                $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12" id="column-2">
                $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12" id="column-3">
                $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12" id="column-4">
                $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATES**

**template.tpl**

```
<div class="layout1template" id="main-content" role="main">
        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12 row-one" id="column-1">
                $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12 row-two" id="column-2">
                $processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12 row-three" id="column-3">
                $processor.processColumn("column-3", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portlet-layout">
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12 row-four" id="column-4">
                $processor.processColumn("column-4", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-content {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row-one {
  height: 15%;
}

.row-two {
  height: 25%;
}

.row-three {
  height: 30%;
}

.row-four {
  height: 30%;
}
```

Comment: 100 % of what? window height or `main-content` height? Did you already tried to find an answer, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331716/css-position-with-percent/18331945#18331945)?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke I have tried but did'nt work

Comment: You should always add things you have tried so far (and why it didn't work) to your question - otherwise it may get closed as duplicate.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Take a look at my updates I have tried that but did'nt worked

Answer (score 1):

You are defining height in a row that has a parent without height defined. The height works depending on the parent. So your html needs to be like this:

```
  <div class="layout1template" id="main-content" role="main">
        <div class="portlet-layout row-one">
    -------------------------------^^^^^^^
            <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only span12" id="column-1">
                $processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: now layout row is coming with the said height but the issue is that say when I drag and place a portlet within the row, the corresponding height is not applied to the portlet

Comment: Do I need to do anything for the portlet to apply the layout row height

Comment: It's because the structure changes, I guess. The heights ever works depending on the inmediate parent height. If this changes, it will be weird behaviour

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Define the heights in the divs that are inmediate childs of `#main-content`

Comment: I am not getting that......to which all childs.....and what heights I need to give

Comment: See the code in the answer. The `row-one` classname I been moved to the parent element, that's a inmediate child of `#main-content`. What is that you don't understand?

Comment: that I have already given height for `.row-one`, `.row-two`, `.row-three`, `.row-four`

Comment: I make a fiddle for you. That's very very simple, I don't know why don't you understand it. See it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/fkqwu6x7/

Comment: Thats the same why I have used in my liferay layout. The issue comes when I place my portlets within the layouts row. Portlets which are placed and not adjusting its height respective to the layout row

Comment: The childrens of the rows needs to be 100% height to occupy all available height